# Don't have permission to delete folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, permissions, ownership

I recently installed an SSD into my computer and put a fresh install of Win 7 on it. I was going through the folders of my old HDD to try and free up some space, but it wouldn't let me delete the Windows folder. I even tried claiming ownership of it as per [this webpage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx), but it still couldn't be deleted.

Comment: You can use Ubuntu live cd to delete a folder if unable to delete in windows

Comment: I already stated that I tried to claim ownership of the folder, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a hidden system file in that directory or in a sub-directory.

Try this command from a command prompt:

```
CD X:\Windows
ATTRIB -R -A -S -H *.* /S /D
CD ..
RD Windows
```

Where X: is the drive letter for the SSD drive.

Comment: What specifically do these commands do? Just want to be safe.

Comment: It won't let me CD to my hdd anyway, when I try to it doesn't do anything.